# Cross-referencing UML models in VS 2010

Tags: uml

I am just starting to explore/use the UML modeling support in Visual Studio 2010 Umltimate.  I have created two model projects within a single solution.  Let's call them Model A and Model B.  I have some data types (classes) defined in Model B.  I want to use them as return types for operations in Model A.  However, I cannot figure out how to make the types defined in Model B show up in Model A when attempting to set return type on an operation.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this release, all the types must be in the same model.